# A floating-point value will have 2 digits after the decimal place and will occupy 8 places

Tags: c#, string, decimal

Suppose, I have a float value [`-12.3456`]. I want to show it like [  `-12.34`].

I wrote the following:

```
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{x:0.00, 8}{y:0.00, 8}{z:0.00, 8}";
    }
```

but, the output is not what I expect.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, it should be

```
float f = (float)-12.3456;
string str = f.ToString("0.00").PadLeft(8);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

```
using System;

public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("[{0, 10:0.00}]", -12.3456);
    }
}
```